# how to set background image properly in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I am working on a view based app, I have set the background image as follows.

.h file:

```
UIImageView *BackgroundImage;
```

.m file:

viewdidLoad method:

```
BackgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]];
[[self view] addSubview:BackgroundImage];
[BackgroundImage.superview sendSubviewToBack:BackgroundImage];
```

and on the rotate method:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{

BackgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG2.png"]];
[[self view] addSubview:BackgroundImage];
[BackgroundImage.superview sendSubviewToBack:BackgroundImage];
[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Using this code I am able to set the background, but on rotation the first loaded image is not removed and the second one is loading just behind the first one, so just half of the image is visible, because of the first image is in front of second one.

Is there is a better way to do this?

*OR*

How can I just remove the first image and then set the second one?

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Hi, just a coding style point - variable names in Objective-C should start with a lower case letter, class names with upper case. So `BackgroundImage` should actually be `backgroundImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your didRotate... method to:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{
    [BackgroundImage removeFromSuperview];
    BackgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG2.png"]];
    [[self view] addSubview:BackgroundImage];   
}
```

Notice the **[BackgroundImage removeFromSuperview];** line. What we are doing here is whenever the device rotates, you remove the old image view and add another one.

Also please notice that variable names should start with lower case, so BackgroundImage should be backgroundImage. This is to tell them apart from classes' names.

Comment: @Zaibi That is a different question. You should search stackoverflow for questions on that topic, and if you don't find an answer then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your code like this should to work

```
BackgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:BackgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:BackgroundImage];

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{

     [BackgroundImage removeFromSuperview];
     BackgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG2.png"]];
     [self.view addSubview:BackgroundImage];
     [self.view sendSubviewToBack:BackgroundImage];
     [super viewDidLoad];

 }
```

Comment: if for some view i have to restrict the app that on rotation the view should remain in portrait view…. then what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are initializing the UIImageview again. Better to use same UIImageView that is backgroundImage with different image.

[Background Image set image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG2.png"]];

Answer (score 0):

Just set the new image when rotating:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{
    BackgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BG2.png"];
}
```

Your code kept adding new image views when rotating.

> How [do stuff] properly in iOS?

- Start your ivar names using an underscore and a lowercase letter: `_backgroundImage` instead of `BackgroundImage`.
- Insert a subview in the right spot: `[self.view insertSubview:_backgroundImage atIndex:0];`

Comment: Will this change the frame of the imageview too?

Comment: @Thedude No it doesn't. Is that needed? The OP did not say anything about changing the frame.

Comment: While it's true the OP did not say anything, since the device is rotating and it is the background image that is being set, I supposed both images would have different frames.

Comment: @Thedude That depends on where the image view is inserted. The window does not rotate. Also, even if the view is further down the view hierarchy and the superview *does* rotate, there's often no need to adjust the frame because usually image views don't clip their contents. And a third reason might be that auto layout or autoresizing do the job of adjusting the frame.

Comment: no it just updated the new background image but not remove the first one.. see my question...

Comment: @Thedude i have marked your answer as right one it resolved my issue.